# How to make a domain point to my site hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, dns, windows-services, ip

Sorry if this is a silly question. I used to know how to do this, but now GoDaddy has changed their UI so much that I'm not sure.

In IIS I added a binding for `mysite.com` for my website. Then in GoDaddy I bought the `mysite.com` domain. Suppose my public DNS for my site is

```
ec2-32-258-223-00.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

and the public IP is `32.258.229.30`. How do I connect the dots?

In GoDaddy under `manage/mysite.com/dns` there is "Forwarding" and "Nameservers", but I'm not sure if either of those are what I want. So confusing. Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To point your domain to a specific EC2 instance:

- Create an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html). This is a static IP address that will remain associated with your EC2 instance. If you use an auto-assigned IP address, it might change when your instance is stopped/started.
- In GoDaddy, [create an `A` record for your domain](https://au.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238) that points to the Elastic IP address of your instance

Alternatively, you could configure GoDaddy to send all DNS requests to **Amazon Route 53** and you could do the above configuration within Route 53 itself. See: [Old article showing how to redirect a subdomain from GoDaddy to Route 53](http://blog.sefindustries.com/redirect-a-subdomain-to-route-53-from-godaddy/)

Comment: That GoDaddy documentation for creating an A record is outdated. I can't find the equivalent panel in the new UI. :(

Comment: If an article on the GoDaddy website is out-of-date, then ask their support team for an updated article.